# UBUNTU 22.04.3LTS on ACER SWIFT 314-44-R6RS: Bluetooth cannot be started (toggle button stays gray)

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, acer

I just installed UBUNTU 22.04LTS on my ACER SWIFT 314-44, in a dual-boot with the pre-installed Windows11.
Installation worked fine, with complete update and upgrade allowed and effective during the installation process.
After rebooting, new updates were automatically offered, accepted and installed.And reboot again.Through the terminal I checked that no more updates/updates were available.
Nothing else has been installed afterwards,no parameters changed so it is a clean start.
The double boot works fine.

On windows11, both the Wifi and Bluetooth work fine (strat and stop).

On Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS, the Bluetooth cannot be started: the toggle button can be moved, but it remains grey and no Bluetooth symbol (neither grey nor white) appears beside the wifi symbol in the toolbar.
I have read another thread reporting a similar problem,with a solution provided by `Jeremy31`, but I am unable to see if the root (or the roots!) of this problem is the same.

All I understood is that it was solved for a machine with a previous kernel (5.19 generic).The installation here runs with a 6.2.0-33 generic kernel.

Here are some queries and answers with the terminal, which I hope will help to find and perhaps solve the problem.

```
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ uname -r
6.2.0-33-generic
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$

lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ uname -a
Linux lionel-Swift-SF314-44 6.2.0-33-generic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 10:33:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ 

lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ mokutil --sb
SecureBoot disabled
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$

lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0489:e0e4 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b777 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd ACER FHD User Facing
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c7f Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$


lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth            1036288  13 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$

lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$

lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
[sudo] Mot de passe de lionel : 
[    2.132068] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.132098] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    2.132099] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.132103] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.132105] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.132108] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.650166] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.650169] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.650175] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.208701] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$

lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-09-24 19:29:11 CEST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 540 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18306)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 35ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─540 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

sept. 24 19:29:09 lionel-Swift-SF314-44 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service.>
sept. 24 19:29:10 lionel-Swift-SF314-44 bluetoothd[540]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
sept. 24 19:29:10 lionel-Swift-SF314-44 bluetoothd[540]: Starting SDP server
sept. 24 19:29:10 lionel-Swift-SF314-44 bluetoothd[540]: Bluetooth management i>
sept. 24 19:29:11 lionel-Swift-SF314-44 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
lines 1-17/17 (END)

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-09-24 19:29:11 CEST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 540 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18306)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 35ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─540 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

sept. 24 19:29:09 lionel-Swift-SF314-44 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service>
sept. 24 19:29:10 lionel-Swift-SF314-44 bluetoothd[540]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
sept. 24 19:29:10 lionel-Swift-SF314-44 bluetoothd[540]: Starting SDP server
sept. 24 19:29:10 lionel-Swift-SF314-44 bluetoothd[540]: Bluetooth management >
sept. 24 19:29:11 lionel-Swift-SF314-44 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
~
~
~
~
~
~
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

The hereabove last query & answer do not return to the command line: the terminal has to be shut while a process is still running in the terminal.

```
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0616]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e0cf]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$


lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.099531] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.265790] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.276620] [Firmware Info]: PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] not reserved in ACPI motherboard resources
[    0.282747] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    2.668871] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20221227123243
[    3.641471] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x0101001F
[    3.646458] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.16 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 3
[    3.646485] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
lionel@lionel-Swift-SF314-44:~$
```

Thank you for any help, and any further terminal queries which would be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal do

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-6.2.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-6.2
sudo dkms install btusb/4.1
```

Reboot

I see you had issues, so I made some changes, so do

```
sudo dkms remove btusb/4.1 --all
sudo dkms uninstall btusb/4.1
sudo rm -r /usr/src/btusb-4.1
cd bluetooth-6.2
git pull
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install btusb/4.1
```

Reboot