# Cannot turn on bluetooth on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth

I have searched the same problem but the solutions I found does not work for me. I have an ASUS ROG STRIX with AMD Ryzen9, kernel 6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1, and I cannot turn on bluetooth (if I go to settings,  the switch button in the top bar does nothing...it moves, but it does not really activate bluetooth and does not even change color). 
 Things I tried:

- `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`
- `sudo apt install bluez bluez-tools`
- `sudo apt-get install blueman`
- Checked the existence of folder */lib/firmware/ar3*k and all its content; even tried to clone *git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git* and copy ar3k in place of the old one

None of those seems to work. 
 Some outputs that may be useful:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
```

output:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0616]
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e0df]
Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
Kernel modules: mt7921e
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0b05:19b6 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0489:e0f6 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:5458 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

output:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-12-20 08:35:17 CET; 27min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 767 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18131)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 39ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─767 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

dic 20 08:35:16 MISTER-FDF systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
dic 20 08:35:17 MISTER-FDF bluetoothd[767]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
dic 20 08:35:17 MISTER-FDF bluetoothd[767]: Starting SDP server
dic 20 08:35:17 MISTER-FDF bluetoothd[767]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22>
dic 20 08:35:17 MISTER-FDF systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
```

```
sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth
```

output:

```
[    3.174835] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.174853] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.174855] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.174858] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.174861] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.174864] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.293095] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.293097] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.293101] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.200317] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
```

```
blueman-applet
```

output:

```
blueman-applet 09.04.58 WARNING  PluginManager:147 __load_plugin: Not loading PPPSupport because its conflict has higher priority
blueman-applet 09.04.58 WARNING  PluginManager:147 __load_plugin: Not loading DhcpClient because its conflict has higher priority
blueman-applet 09.04.58 WARNING  DiscvManager:119 update_menuitems: warning: Adapter is None
blueman-applet 09.04.58 ERROR    AgentManager:20 on_register_failed: /org/bluez/obex/agent/blueman org.bluez.obex.Error.AlreadyExists Agent already exists
```

```
blueman-manager
```

output:

```
blueman-manager 09.06.19 ERROR    Manager:137 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 09.06.19 ERROR    Manager:141 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: See if this answer fixes it https://askubuntu.com/a/1486886/300665